# In springboot error sayingThe declared package "com.example.demo" does not match the expected package ""

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

```
package com.example.demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootEdurekaTrialApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootEdurekaTrialApplication.class, args);
    }

}


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/78XDP.png
```

I have shared the screenshot of project package in above image. I have created the class under same package but I don't know why I am getting error. please guide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your directory structure once in the file system. It should contain these three folders com/example/demo and under demo the file should be present. Sometimes folder structure is created as a single folder com.example.demo instead of the  com/example/demo(3 folders). This should be the root cause of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For me I got the same error. The first time around I put the "demo" folder inside another folder that I called "Spring Web". I deleted everything and unzipped "demo" directly to C: and after importing it into Eclipse the error did not appear again.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the directory structure is fine.  It could be that the source path of the main application is pointing to a different directory than the default path such as "src/main/java".  Since this file was automatically created by Spring Boot, there seemed to be no way to fix it.

The way I resolved this compiler error was to add a new class using a different name from scratch and then copy the original content into the new class before removing the old one.  You can then rename the class afterward.

Answer (score 0):

For me directory was proper. I did eclipse re-start then issue went off . Looks Eclipse issue .